# How can I do a check if current object date is 2 days older then current day?

Tags: c#, linq, date, datetime

How can I check if current objects datetime property is 2 days older then current date, if it is want to delete it from the database.

I have to implement it inside this method,

```
public void AddNews(News news)
{
var exists = db.News.Any(x => x.Title == news.Title);

if (exists == false)
{
    db.News.AddObject(news);
}
else
{
    db.News.DeleteObject(news);
}


}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Side note: your method itself seem odd. Why is your `AddNews()` method in the business of *deleting* anything? You may want to restructure/rename a bit so that your methods all do what they say they'll do.

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract 2 [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) values and get a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

```
if((DateTime.Now - news.DateTime).Days >= 2)
{
    // Delete news from database
}
```

Comment: Be careful about `DateTime.Now`.  Use `DateTime.UtcNow`, `DateTimeOffset.Now` or `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` instead.  [Read more](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the property is called `News.Date`...

```
if(news.Date <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2))
{
    db.News.DeleteObject(news);
}
```

Comment: Be careful about `DateTime.Now`.  Use `DateTime.UtcNow`, `DateTimeOffset.Now` or `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` instead.  [Read more](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)